# jquery find first element by class without id

Tags: jquery

```
<img class="image" src="image.png" id="one"/>
<img class="image" src="image.png" id="two"/>
<img class="image" src="image.png"/>
<img class="image" src="image.png"/>
```

How to find next element by class name that don't have id attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(".image:not([id]):first")
```

Without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector(".image:not([id]):first");
```

Comment: I'll upvote if you provide a vanilla answer as well :P

Comment: @RUJordan Added an answer using `querySelector`. I'm not going to bother writing one that uses `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

iterate the img's with `.each` and check by `.attr('id')` ?